# call jQuery function from code behind after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to call a jQuery .click function after page postback from code behind. I'm using ASP.NET with C#.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Where should the code execute. on the client?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do would be to use jQuery to attach to the [`submit` event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) of the form and do whatever processing you require *before* the postback.

```
$('#form-id').submit(function() {
    // Do whatever here
});
```

Also, if you `return true` from this event handler the postback will occur, if you `return false` then the page postback will be prevented.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the click function for an element after the page has successfully reloaded from a postback, you can make use of the [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) function:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "PostbackClick", "$('#myElement').click();", true);
```